# Ant Junit task throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, ant

I have a simple Junit test that keeps throwing a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException. Below is the folder structure

```
project:
|__build.xml
|__hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
|__junit.jar
|__src:
|  |__Simple.java
|__bin:
   |__Simple.class
```

---

```
Simple.java
import org.junit.Test;

public class Simple {
    @Test
    public void check() {
        assert (true);
    }
}
```

---

```
build.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="Ant-Test" default="main">
    <target name="main">
        <junit printsummary="yes" fork="yes" haltonfailure="no">
            <classpath path="hamcrest-core-1.3.jar" />
            <classpath path="junit.jar" />
            <formatter type="plain" />
            <batchtest fork="yes" todir="docs">
                <fileset dir="bin">
                    <include name="**.class" />
                </fileset>
            </batchtest>
        </junit>
    </target>
</project>
```

---

```
Error:
Testsuite: Simple
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
Caused an ERROR
Simple
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Simple
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:292)
```

---

Please help me find the reason for why this error occurs. The script is able to find the test case but at the end an error is thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Add the required resources to the test classpath](https://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#path):

```
<pathelement path="${classpath}"/>
```

that in your case will be:

```
<classpath>
   <pathelement path="bin" />
   <pathelement location="hamcrest-core-1.3.jar" />
   <pathelement location="junit.jar" />
</classpath>
```

As explained [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns)

> To make things a bit more flexible, we add one extra feature, which makes it possible to match multiple directory levels. This can be used to match a complete directory tree, or a file anywhere in the directory tree. To do this, "**" must be used as the name of a directory. When ** is used as the name of a directory in the pattern, it matches zero or more directories. For example: /test/** matches all files/directories under /test/, such as /test/x.java, or /test/foo/bar/xyz.html, but not /xyz.xml.

'**' must be used to match folders, and not as wildcard to select partial file names.
Change your ant with:

```
<fileset dir="bin">
    <include name="*.class" />
</fileset>
```

If you want to select all '*.class' files under every directory under bin/ then use:

```
<fileset dir="bin">
    <include name="**/*.class" />
</fileset>
```

You will have now an error cause by the test report writer. You need to create a docs folder and everything will work.

The final build.xml will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="Ant-Test" default="main">
    <target name="main">
        <mkdir dir="docs"/>
        <junit printsummary="yes" fork="yes" haltonfailure="no">
            <classpath location="hamcrest-core-1.3.jar" />
            <classpath location="junit-4.12.jar" />
            <classpath path="bin/" />
            <formatter type="plain" />
            <batchtest fork="yes" todir="docs">
                <fileset dir="bin">
                    <include name="**/*.class" />
                </fileset>
            </batchtest>
        </junit>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked, had to add bin to classpath and use * for files...

Answer (score 0):

Please try with following fileset tag:

```
<fileset dir="bin">                  
    <include name="**.java" />
</fileset>
```

Comment: classpath must contain "class" files, not java.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if `junit` task admits more than one `classpath` node, but anyway, it is a good practice to have just one. Moreover, your classpath is missing the *classes* directory. The right declaration would be like this:

```
<junit ...>
    <classpath>
        <pathelement path="bin"/>
        <pathelement location="hamcrest-core-1.3.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="junit.jar"/>
    </classpath>
    ...
</junit>
```